# QGIS labels change their position as map is dragged

Tags: qgis, labeling

I spent a while fixing all the labels across my map. Unfortunately, they tend to change their position, as the map is dragged.
I need a bigger map than displayed in the QGIS map canvas.
See the problem below:

[image]

As the map has been dragged south, the labels concerned move too. It applies to all labels across the map.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: How did you place the labels? Normally labels are places dynamically by an algorithm but you can try if Label - Placement - Anchoring - Custom - Strict behavior helps.  Perhaps you want also turn repeated labels off. Another option is to create a point layer for the labels.

Comment: I got the same problem (label are dynamically placed at first but a few are not exactly in the right place so you manually adjust these few label then when you drag the map all other label position are recalculated and again a few need adjustment, if you have hundred of label this became an endless task...). this could help : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191129/how-to-get-coordinates-of-label-position-or-make-static-labels-for-each-feature

Comment: I noticed, that also some layers are shifted a bit. It usually appears when I save the current map canvas as PNG and change the DPI from the default 120 to i.e. 250.

Comment: @J.R Honestly, with hundreds of labels, I would never consider manually placing them or even getting their center coordinates because they can't follow curved lines correctly. Might as well just create a layer specifically for line labels with one short feature per label. Having a fixed length locks the label between the start and end.

Comment: @GabrielC. Exactly when you have lots of labels manually placing them is not an option. The labeling engine does a better job (by evaluating several position for each label and choosing the "best" one) than creating a "label layer" (How to create one where each label is perfectly placed ? if by manually editing it I'm back to steep one). So letting the labeling engine do most of the work and manually improving a few label seem an ideal compromise, but for that you need to be able to lock the label position...

Comment: @J.R That's what I create a separate layer for: the problematic labels. It's easier to just flag them to be hidden in the original layer using an attribute, without touching the rest. I think  I wasn't clear on that in my other comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#control-anchor-point-for-line-labels), you can control the anchor point for the labeling and place it exactly at a certain percentage of the line: here, I chose at 20% from the start-point of the line:

[image]

Comment: I have got 3.12 so far, that's why I couldn't find this option anywhere

Comment: What is great: QGIS grows very fast, so every 4 month with a new release you get a lot of new functions. It's always worth having a look to the visual changelogs for new features: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html